# What does for places mean to “ be ramified over $\mathbb Q$”?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I saw the following sentences in a paper :

Let F be a number field containing the group of $2n$-th roots of unity. Let S be a finite set of places of F containing  all the archimedean ones and all non-archimedean primes which are ramified over $\mathbb Q$.

I have a question here.
What does for places mean to be ramified over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: It means that the corresponding prime is ramified in the extension $F/\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: It remains to define a ramified archimedean place. In an extension of number fields, the usual convention is that a complex place is unramified, and a real place is ramified if it becomes complex . But in the latter case, an equally justified convention is to say that the real place splits, see e.g. G. Gras' book "CFT:from theory to practice".